# C++ How to average a string of numbers?

Tags: c++, math

I have a problem with something I was trying to work out.

If I had a string of numbers with spaces like "10 20 30 40", is there any way I can add those numbers up and average them out?

I tried the below code but it returned 'nan', so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numLength; i++)
{
    num = grades.at(i) - '0';
    total += num;
    countNum++;
}

cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " average: " << (total/countNum) << endl;
```

Comment: Use `std::istringstream` instead of trying to figure out what and what is not a digit.

Comment: *Is there any way I can add those numbers up and average them out?* -- You're using C++.  If a language as powerful as C++ can't get the average from a string of numbers, then that would be shocking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to manually parse the data, you can simply use [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string test = "10 20 30 40";
   int count = 0;
   double total = 0.0;
   std::istringstream strm(test);
   int num;
   while ( strm >> num )
   {
       ++count;
       total += num;
   }
   std::cout << "The average is " << total / count;
}
```

Output:

```
The average is 25
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Since I'm a beginner could you please explain how to type the istringstream function using namespace std? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to state.  A `std::istringstream` works as if you typed in those numbers from the keyboard, if you want a layman / beginner explanation of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::istringstream` to parse the string, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
...

std::istringstream iss(grades);
while (iss >> num) {
    total += num;
    ++countNum;
}
std::cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " average: " << (total/countNum) << std::endl;
```